# Why do I get "Routing error" even though my path is in "rake routes"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rake, ruby-on-rails-5

I’m using Rails 5.  I have this in my rake routes

```
localhost:sims nataliab$ rake routes
                         Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                   Controller#Action
    scenario_confidential_memos GET    /scenarios/:scenario_id/confidential_memos(.:format)          confidential_memos#index
                                POST   /scenarios/:scenario_id/confidential_memos(.:format)          confidential_memos#create
 new_scenario_confidential_memo GET    /scenarios/:scenario_id/confidential_memos/new(.:format)      confidential_memos#new
edit_scenario_confidential_memo GET    /scenarios/:scenario_id/confidential_memos/:id/edit(.:format) confidential_memos#edit
     scenario_confidential_memo GET    /scenarios/:scenario_id/confidential_memos/:id(.:format)      confidential_memos#show
                                PATCH  /scenarios/:scenario_id/confidential_memos/:id(.:format)      confidential_memos#update
                                PUT    /scenarios/:scenario_id/confidential_memos/:id(.:format)      confidential_memos#update
                                DELETE /scenarios/:scenario_id/confidential_memos/:id(.:format)      confidential_memos#destroy
                      scenarios GET    /scenarios(.:format)                                          scenarios#index
                                POST   /scenarios(.:format)                                          scenarios#create
                   new_scenario GET    /scenarios/new(.:format)                                      scenarios#new
                  edit_scenario GET    /scenarios/:id/edit(.:format)                                 scenarios#edit
                       scenario GET    /scenarios/:id(.:format)                                      scenarios#show
                                PATCH  /scenarios/:id(.:format)                                      scenarios#update
                                PUT    /scenarios/:id(.:format)                                      scenarios#update
                                DELETE /scenarios/:id(.:format)                                      scenarios#destroy
```

Yet when I start my rails development server and visit http://localhost:3000/sims/scenarios/new , I get the error

```
Routing Error

No route matches [GET] "/sims/scenarios/new"
```

Why do I get this error when my path is in my rake routes?

Comment: You have pretty much answered the question yourself. Try running `rake routes | grep "/sims/"` as you have no route which matches "/sims/scenarios/new".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prefix `sims` is not present on the url I guess you meant. It would be http://localhost:3000/scenarios/new, ain't it?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to organize your `scenarios` under a `sims` namespace ? if so, check out routing in this guide:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing

In essence, you'd want to have something like:

`namespace :sims do
  resources :scenarios do
    resources :confidential_memos
  end
end`